# Using multiple conditions in an Oracle WHEN CASE

Tags: database, oracle, case

I'm having some issues with using a CASE in a CASE, where I need to perform two checks in the WHEN clause and it fails, ex:

```
CASE
WHEN trim(to_char(sysdate,'DAY')) = 'TUESDAY' THEN
CASE 
WHEN ((max(trunc(initial_date)) < trunc(sysdate)) AND name like 'Ma%') OR ((max(trunc(initial_date)) < trunc(sysdate)) AND name like 'Rna%') THEN 'something'
WHEN ((max(trunc(initial_date)) < trunc(sysdate)) AND name like '%ame') OR ((max(trunc(initial_date)) < trunc(sysdate)) AND name like '%ore') THEN 'somethingelse'
END
ELSE 'noproblemo'
END
as 'info',
'username' as username
from DBtable@dblink
where initialdate < trunc(sysdate)
and details = 'Criteria for search'
```

it now throws:

ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
ORA-02063: preceding line from DBLINK

Any pointers are much appreciate

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed another `END`  since it is `NESTED CASE EXPRESSION`

```
CASE
    WHEN trim(to_char(sysdate,'DAY')) = 'TUESDAY' THEN
    (CASE 
    WHEN ((max(trunc(initial_date)) over() < trunc(sysdate)) AND name like 'Ma%') OR ((max(trunc(initial_date))  over() < trunc(sysdate)) AND name like 'Rna%') THEN 'something'
    WHEN ((max(trunc(initial_date))  over() < trunc(sysdate)) AND name like '%ame') OR ((max(trunc(initial_date)) over() < trunc(sysdate)) AND name like '%ore') THEN 'somethingelse'
    ELSE 'noproblemo'
    END)
    END,
    'username' as username
    from DBtable@dblink
    where initialdate < trunc(sysdate)
    and details = 'Criteria for search'
```

Comment: i've updated the query. the END is there. the issue seems to be multiple operations in the WHEN clause?

Comment: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function ORA-02063: preceding line from DBLINK

Comment: I edited my answer to fix ORA-00937: not a single-group group function.           And to fix  ORA-02063: preceding line from DBLINK error kindly a look into this https://community.oracle.com/thread/3904205